# Change monitor resolution

Tags: resolution

Since monitor on  laptop broke, is there a solution to lower the resolution and put it in the bottom right corner? 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imk3Z.jpg)
Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't feel like a stack overflow question, stack overflow is for coding questions. I would suggest looking at some tech support websites. Or, if you have an alternative monitor, you could try hooking that up to your computer.

Comment: I'm sorry for that thought i could post any software issue, do you have any sites where i can share my problem?

Comment: Try this one, or if that doesn't work just ask on the HP support community page, which is where this guy asked. https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/How-do-you-change-screen-size/td-p/1432633